# C: stdin and std* errs

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I want to manipulate `Stdin` and then `Std*`. But I am getting the following errors,

```
$ gcc testFd.c                                                                 
testFd.c:9: error: initializer element is not constant
testFd.c:9: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
testFd.c:10: error: redefinition of `fd'
testFd.c:9: error: `fd' previously defined here
testFd.c:10: error: `mode' undeclared here (not in a function)
testFd.c:10: error: initializer element is not constant
testFd.c:10: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
testFd.c:12: error: syntax error before string constant
```

The program is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int STDIN_FILENO = 1;
// I want to access typed 
// Shell commands, dunno about the value:
unsigned long F_DUPFD;

fd = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_DUPFD, 0);
fd = open("/dev/fd/0", mode);

printf("STDIN = %s", fd);
```

**Updated Errors: just trying to get an example program about file descriptors to work in C, pretty lost with the err report**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main (void) {
    int STDIN_FILENO;
    // I want to access typed 
    // Shell commands, dunno about the value:
    unsigned long F_DUPFD;
    int fd;
    const char mode = 'r';

    fd = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_DUPFD, 0);
    /* also, did you mean `fopen'? */
    fd = fopen("/dev/fd/0", mode);

    printf("STDIN = %s", fd);

    return 0;
}
```

The program execution is shown below.

```
$ gcc testFd.c                                                                
testFd.c: In function `main':
testFd.c:14: warning: passing arg 2 of `fopen' makes pointer from integer without a cast
testFd.c:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `main` method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main (void) {
    int STDIN_FILENO = 1;
    // I want to access typed 
    // Shell commands, dunno about the value:
    unsigned long F_DUPFD;
    /* also, declare the type of your variable "fd" */
    int fd;

    fd = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_DUPFD, 0);
    /* also, did you mean `fopen'? */
    fd = open("/dev/fd/0", mode);

    printf("STDIN = %s", fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot your main() function!!

Answer (score 2):

Where's your definition of `main()`?

Answer (score 2):

Quite apart from the fact that you don't have a `main()` function, your entire approach is wrong.  `STDIN_FILENO` is a constant; assigning to it doesn't make any sense.

Try explaining what you actually want to *do*, with some detail, and we will be able to suggest how to go about it.

Comment: Yeah, there was a lot I didn't get to in my answer, mainly because I was confused as to what the OP was trying to do.