# How to redirect assert output in C++?

Tags: c++, redirect, assert, stderr, ofstream

Is it possible to redirect *assert* output to a file when its parameter is false? I know its default behavior is to write a message to stderr, but the following didn't work as I expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ofstream ofs;
   ofs.open("test.txt", ios_base::out);
   ofs << "A";
   cerr << "B";
   cerr.rdbuf(ofs.rdbuf());
   cerr << "C";
   assert(1 == 2);
   return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Results in *test.txt*:

```
AC
```

And results in stdout:

```
B
Assertion failed: 1 == 2, file C:\xxx\Unit1.cpp, line 14
Abnormal program termination
```

I was expecting that these 2 last lines printed in stdout were in *test.txt* file though.
I've also tried using, instead of...

```
cerr.rdbuf(ofs.rdbuf());
```

the following:

```
freopen("test.txt", "a", stderr);
```

but it hasn't worked as well.

I've also seen some posts (as [C: how to redirect stderr from System-command to stdout or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019630/c-how-to-redirect-stderr-from-system-command-to-stdout-or-file)) suggesting *dup2* to redirect streams such as stderr, which that is defined in *unistd.h*. But I'm at Windows using C++Builder and it doesn't seem available.

Comment: What platform are you on?  [`freopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) works for me.

Comment: the C:\ in the output indicates Windows ;-)

Comment: Johannes guessed right: Windows

Comment: On Windows `_dup()` and `_dup2()` are available in [io.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: After including `<io.h>` and calling `_dup2(ofs, 2)`, I get compilation error: '"E2268 Call to undefined function _dub2"'. Isn't it only available for Visual Studio compiler? I'm using Borland's C++Builder 6 compiler bcc32.

Comment: @Baumann for C++ builder it may be correctly called `dup2` without the '_'. (Microsoft really likes to mess with peoples' heads) The symbol is exported from `cc3289mt.dll` so it is definitely part of your runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect all output to stderr, or any other standard file handle to a file at the start of your program.

```
   freopen( "error.log","w",stderr);
```

Read about this here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/58667

@edit: if the output goes to stdout, then you need to do:

```
   freopen( "error.log","w",stdout );
```

If you want to append and not overwrite the error.log:

```
   freopen( "error.log","aw",stdout );
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tested and it keeps writing the assert message in stdout. Besides, the content of the file is overwritten, which is undesirable.

Comment: ALso - I find it incomprehensibly broken that an implementation of "assert" sends its output to stdout. Wow. Does it really do that?

Comment: Even using `freopen("test.txt", "aw", stdout);`, it keeps printing assert message in stdout, not in the file.

Comment: When I say the program has printed something to stdout, I meant that the message could be seen in the windows prompt when the program is executed from cmd.exe.

Comment: Its probably going to stderr. Is your assert happening before you enter main? If so, you'll have to do the freopen earlier - like in the constructor to the static class which is asserting.

Comment: I've tried something similar in my real code. But the problem is that not even the example code I've posted together with the question is working. The functions `freopen("test.txt", "aw", stderr);` and `cerr.rdbuf(ofs.rdbuf());` are redirecting the stream properly to the file, except when the message is sent by the assert function.