# Why does redirecting the output of assert() work when done using freopen() and stderr but not when redirecting the buffer of std::cerr normally?

Tags: c++, assert, cout, assertion, freopen

I'd like to redirect the output that `assert()` creates when an assertion fails, so that it is written to a log file instead of the output window. I assumed `assert()` uses `std::cerr` to output but when redirecting `std::cerr` to my log file, `assert()` still outputs to the output window and not my file:

```
std::ofstream ofs("log-file.txt");
std::cerr.rdbuf(ofs.rdbuf());

assert(false); // Still outputs "Assertion failed: false" to the output window and not to the log file
```

I found an [SO question with a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850867/how-to-redirect-assert-output-in-c) and its answer suggested to use `freopen` instead, like so:

```
freopen("log-file.txt", "w", stderr);
```

This gives me an error saying `'freopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using freopen_s instead.`

`freopen_s` seems to take different arguments than `freopen` and I can't get it to work.

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034465/13699024) suggested to use `freopen` but simply add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to the Command Line in Visual Studio Project Properties. This indeed removed the error and `assert()` now correctly outputs to my log file.

But this all seems unnecessarily complicated. It feels like there should be a smooth way of achieving what I want to do without suppressing level 3 compiler warnings. Why can't I simply redirect the buffer normally of whatever `assert()` is using to output? What exactly **is** `assert()` using to output, if it's not `std::cout`, `std::cerr` or `std::clog`? (I have tried redirecting all three)

Comment: Since `assert()` is a C library function, it would be quite a neat trick for it to use a C++ class for its output.

Comment: _"this all seems unnecessarily complicated"_ - It is, because they descided to disable some standard functions in MSVC making it necessary to define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` if you want to use those functions in MSVC. Otherwise, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Not that I think `freopen_s` or the other "security" functions Microsoft tries to force you to use are all that useful compared to properly using the functions they replace, but it isn't hard to use. There's even an example on the documentation page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/freopen-s-wfreopen-s?view=msvc-170

Comment: In Visual Studio, the redirection of `stderr` will only work for console applications. Consider creating your own assert-like macro instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is using `freopen` to do this common? Shouldn't redirecting the output of `assert` be a very common thing in C++? I mean, don't most real life code use some sort of external logging, that you would want to be updated when an assertion fails? Surely the program silently exiting while outputing the reason to the wrong place is never desired behavior?

Comment: @JensB I don't know how common it is to do the redirecting from within the program that uses the `assert`. I think that's usually done by the program invoking the program. `./program > log 2> err` or similar - but if you want both the raw C stream and the C++ layer to be redirected, `freopen` should be the thing to use. If you only care about the C++ streams, you can set a new `rdbuf()` ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/xv6qaW8r8)) - but then again, `assert` doesn't use the C++ streams, so that's probably not useful.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm, not sure I understand what this example means: `./program > log 2> err`? Where would one write this?

Comment: @JensB That's what the executor of `program` would write to redirect the output to different places. `stdout` would go to `log` and `stderr` would go to `err`. That works whether you run it manually or if there is some system daemon responsible for bringing up a number of processes. Typically, `assert`s are removed when compiling for a release though. Then proper logging facilities are used instead. `assert` is only a development thing so the one redirecting the output would probably be a unit test wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

your process has an OS buffer called `stderr`, this is where `assert` prints to as it is a C function, on the other hand `std::cerr` is a c++ object that prints text that gets pushed **into std::cerr** to the `stderr` buffer.

modifying `std::cerr` object will change the buffer `std:cerr` will print to, but it will not modify the underlying OS `stderr` buffer where `assert` is printing directly, in order to modify that you need an OS specific function such as `freopen` or `dup2` (whose implementation is defined by the OS, as they are modifying OS buffers)